# ASP.NET Gridview SQL Datasource

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I am setting up a Gridview to display data from a SQL database. I know I can set it up in the aspx page or in the code behind. Is there a best practice to follow on deciding the best approach? Do you normally set it up in the code behind?

Answer (score 0):

The `SqlDataSource` control is a server control just like the `GridView` control is, so to answer your question there really is no "better" (declaratively only versus imperatively only) way to use server controls.

The few times I have used the `SqlDataSource` control, I have always declared the control in the markup and set the properties for the data retrieval inside of the markup as well.

Reality usually dictates that you will declare your server controls in your markup for both the `GridView` and the `SqlDataSource` and then apply/update the properties of the server controls in your code behind, but probably you will write more code-behind for a `GridView` than a `SqlDataSource`, because the `GridView` needs to react to events on the rows within the grid. If you do not have any dynamic queries, then most of the time your `SqlDataSource` will have static queries that can be applied in the markup (decaratively).